# C# LDAP SEARCH WITHOUT BIND

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I would like to ask if there is a LDAP C# function that allows me to do a search in the AD without the need to call the bind?

I tried using LDP.exe, windows GUI LDAP tool, to search through the AD, it returns the information correctly, however, as I do not have access to the AD, I do not know the credentials needed to bind with the AD.

I had tried using LDIDFE.exe, windows command line LDAP tool, to search the AD, it returned me a mix of incorrect and correct information. Does anyone knows why?

I believe LDP.exe used the C++ function ldap_search_s to carry out the search. Is there any ways I can do this in C#?

Thank you.

Comment: If you don't have access to LDAP, and have no credentials to connect - **no**, then you **cannot** access it. No "magic" function will give you that access......

Answer (score 0):

If your program is running on a computer joined to the domain of interest, and you know only your credentials and not any elevated account, you can at least enumerate various objects like user accounts and security groups.

You can use [AD powershell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rkramesh/archive/2012/01/17/how-to-add-active-directory-module-in-powershell-in-windows-7.aspx), or use .net's [System.DirectoryServices Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**The [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace is newer, simpler and preferred way**, unless there is something you cannot do using it, then you can use [System.DirectoryServices Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices(v=vs.110).aspx)

The following example is copied from [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);

UserPrincipal usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, 
                                           IdentityType.SamAccountName, 
                                           "Guest");

if(usr != null)
{
    if (usr.Enabled == false)
        usr.Enabled = true;

    usr.Save();
    usr.Dispose();
}
ctx.Dispose();
```

Comment: my computer do have access to the ldap server. I could use the LDP.exe in windows to search for the information I need but the ldidfe.exe command line function would not work. I was thinking it might be due to the fact that ldidfe application does a bind before a search while the ldp application does not. Thus, I am trying to look for a way to simply search like what the ldp.exe application does using C#. Any ideas? thank you.

Comment: @jiaming the code above _is_ C#. Download Visual Studio Express Edition (free) from www.visualstudio.com and try the links and code above.